# error parsing xml not well-formed (invalid token) error on android

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I am getting above error for this code. But I don't see  any spelling error here.

```
 < TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First Name"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a space between `<` and `TextView`. It should be as follows

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="First Name"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>
```